# CGContextAddArc: how to create circle?

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-graphics, sprite-kit

I started working on my Tower defense project in Xcode with the new Spritekit framework and I wanted to add a visible radius (circle) around ANY tower that the player would create.

So I created the following code:

```
// Place Towers
-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    /* Called when a mouse click occurs */

    CGPoint location = [theEvent locationInNode:self];

    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"tower"];

    sprite.position = location;
    sprite.scale = 1.5;

    CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextAddArc(myContext, location.x, location.y, 10, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(myContext, 0, 0, 225, 0);

    [self addChild:sprite];

}
```

I'm not familiar with the angles and other things because I am doing this for the first time, so I'm just guessing that it should be like that.  I'm pretty sure that I missed something.

Thanks for any advice (I await some great criticism).

Comment: Does it produce the expected result? If not, what result do you get and what do you expect? - *"I'm just guessing that it should be like that"* is not a question at all!

Comment: it doesn't produce anything, just the sprite itself and no circle.. sorry about that, 1. time posting something here..

Comment: Why not use a SKShapeNode ? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly from the SpriteKit programming guide :

```
SKShapeNode *ball = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];

CGMutablePathRef myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(myPath, NULL, 0,0, 15, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
ball.path = myPath;

ball.lineWidth = 1.0;
ball.fillColor = [SKColor blueColor];
ball.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
ball.glowWidth = 0.5;
```

Comment: i tried the code above (with change of location), sysnthetized myPath, etc.. nothing :/ could it be that my background image is overlaying it?

Comment: i tried NSLog(@"Ball created!") if the function runs, it does, but it doesn't show anything at all.

Comment: i figured it out :D forgot to [self addChild:ball]

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easier to use [`CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-BCICBBJF). So if you wanted a circle of radius 10, centered at (x,y) it would be:

```
const CGFloat color[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1 }; // Alpha should be 1, not 0!
CGContextSetStrokeColor (myContext, color); 
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect (myContext, CGRectMake(x - 10, y - 10, 20, 20));
```

Comment: yeah, it should, i don't know if i get it the way you mean it, so if you could post some code or anything? it would be great

Comment: Actually, I just realized there's a `CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect()` which does the stroke all at once!